# Is there any Firebug version for Firefox Nightly 13.0a1?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I googled for the add-on, but when I go to Mozilla's website, it shows a message that there is no Firebug add-on for 13.0a1. Is there any Firebug version available for this Firefox version?

Comment: In nightly maybe just use the built in devleoper tools.

Comment: @Noitidart In the mentioned Nightly the built-in DevTools were not much developed.

Answer (score 1):

The last Firebug version working with Firefox 13.0a1 is [1.10.6](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/1.10.6), as you can see in the [compatibility table at addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=stackoverflow).

Though Firefox 13.0a1 is [outdated for years](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/). You should download the latest stable version (currently 34.0.5) or the latest [Firefox Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) (currently 37.0a1).

The Firebug version compatible with this Nightly is 3.0, which is currently in alpha state and [can be downloaded from getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/3.0/).